# Loop Mutliple JSON objects to get multiple values

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

Using JSON.Net (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) and the following C# code:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
@{

    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me&fields=id%2Cname%2Cposts.limit(3)&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1";
    var syncClient = new WebClient();
    var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

    JObject facebook = JObject.Parse(content);

    //To-Do: Loop each JSON object to get message, image, & link values.
}
```

How would I loop each JSON object to get message, image, & link values given the following JSON format (http://www.codeshare.io/EvIdN).

Comment: @Brendan Green Thanks for the edit. I was posting from a mobile device which made editing difficult. I don't really see that a small edit deserves a down vote (stuff like this makes me hate stakeoverflow at times), but thanks anyway. Or does stackoverflow automatically down vote for each edit?

Comment: There aren't any automatic downvotes. Someone (not me) has read your question and taken a dislike to it. I don't know what json resources are out there, but I'm guessing that you were downvoted because the question shows a lack of prior research.

Comment: @DeanOC Thanks. No worries I've become use to the passive aggressive esque culture in the software / tech industry. Thanks for the post and clarification!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @src0010 I edited, but did not downvote your question.

Comment: @John Sauders Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I was trying to be as descriptive as possible, but can see where that may be redundant with tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [indexer](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm):

```
foreach (var element in facebook["posts"]["data"])
{
    message = element["message"];
    image = element["image"];
    //etc
}
```

[Here is an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cHDyCz), and by the way your JSON is invalid...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will give this a try later today and credit your answer if everything works out! Thanks again!

Comment: That worked great, thanks!  Sorry for the invalid JSON I was  quickly censoring out account data so I could provide an example of the basic data structure.  Thanks again!